# Hosea 2:16-17 or Hosea 2:14-15?

Tags: reference-request, verse-identification, hosea

Should the following scriptures be Hosea 2:16-17 or Hosea 2:14-15 Complete Jewish Bible:

> “But now I am going to woo her —
>   I will bring her out to the desert
>   and I will speak to her heart.
>   I will give her her vineyards from there
>   and the Akhor Valley as a gateway to hope.
>   She will respond there as she did when young,
>   as she did when she came up from Egypt.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! To get oriented on this site, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Despite the tag, we don't really do reference requests here. But on your question, Jewish Bibles use somewhat different chapter and verse divisions than Christian Bibles do. For more on this, see [Chapters and verses of the Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible). When citing Bible verses here, it's best to provide the actual text, or link to it on one of the Bible sites, so that it's clear what you're referring to.

Answer (score 4):

The Complete Jewish Bible you are looking at (notably, not a Jewish translation at all) is following the numbering scheme of the [Masoretic Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text) where that text corresponds with 2:16-17. In most Christian English translations, this is labeled 2:14-15. ([JPS Tanakh](http://www.breslov.com/bible/Hosea2.htm#16) and [Judaica Press Tanach](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16156/jewish/Chapter-2.htm) also use the Masoretic numbering.)

The difference arises because the numbering system of the Masoretic Text ends Chapter 1 after verse 9, whereas in [Christian translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Hosea%201:10) it usually ends after verse 11. The shift in mood between 1:9 and 2:1 (MT; 1:9 and 1:10 in English) has been the [subject of much commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=zhtvJDLa9GUC&lpg=PA177&ots=EIRB44e51p&dq=shift%20between%20hosea%201%3A9%20and%202%3A1&pg=PA177#v=onepage&q&f=false), and some consider 2:1 to be the beginning of a 'rhetorical unit,' making the numbering of the MT appealing. But that is beyond the scope of the question.